# How to display image on web browser using Tornado Python server?

Tags: python, tornado

The error says the the indent is at the "if _name" etc. part.. I'm not sure why it would indicate this.

```
class GetFileHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        fileid = self.get_argument('fileid', "")

        cur.execute("""SELECT filepath FROM files_table WHERE file_id = %s""", (fileid, ))
        m = cur.fetchall()
        y = m[0]
        x = y[0]

        path = x + "/" + fileid + ".jpg"

        try:
            with open(path, 'rb') as f:
                data = f.read()
                self.write(data)
            self.finish()
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    tornado.options.parse_command_line() 
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/getit", GetFileHandler)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app) 
    http_server.listen(options.port) 
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: If `get` is a method of `GetFileHandler`, it should be indented.

Comment: @RubenBermudez thats true ... but im sure thats just an indentation error that came from OP copy/paste to python ...  the error indicates that it expects an `except`

Comment: def get need to be indented as well as double indent for a if condition which comes under def

Answer (score 3):

`try` expects an `except`

```
try:
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
        self.write(data)
    self.finish()
except IOError:
    print "Failed!!"
```

in order to get it to show up as an image you will need to set the content header to reflect that it is an image mime-type ...

Comment: Well, an `except` or a `finally`. But neither one seems all that useful here (actually seeing the error message, instead of just seeing that something failed, is a lot better for debugging, especially when you haven't even gotten a first version working…), so I think just getting rid of the `try` is probably a better fix…

Comment: I don't disagree ... but I was trying to provide him a working version with as little change to his code as possible (although just removing the try would have probably been close to the amount of change catching it did ... I just assumed(perhaps foolishly) he would be doing some error handing that he hadnt included

Comment: Makes sense—and I already upvoted your answer; I just wanted to add a comment. Maybe I'm jaded, but when I see someone posting code with a `try` and no `except` and not understanding why it's a problem, I assume they've just copied and pasted a fragment of someone else's code without understanding its structure…

Comment: @abarnert I wouldnt assume that is wrong ... I see a whole lot of questions where that is obviously the case :P  (those are almost as bad as the verbatim copy and paste of what are clearly homework assignments)

Comment: My favorite one of those homework assignments was the one that included the instructions, "You may ask for help on sites like StackOverflow, but do not post this entire assignment as a question" at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the except block to match the get function? You should add, at a minimum, something like the following to the function.

```
except IOError as xcpt:
    # IO error handling
    raise xcpt  # if you want to propagate the exception
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a separate folder for images and want to serve them as static content with a url e.g.

```
http://yourwebsite.com/images/yourimage.jpg
```

then you can make use of `tornado.web.StaticFileHandler` :

```
handlers = [
        (r"/images/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': "./images"}),
        (r"/", WebHandler)
]
```